# When can I call injected javascript function automatically in android webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I inject the JavaScript function in `override WebViewClient.OnPageFinished`

```
public class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{ 
  public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url)
  {
     view.EvaluateJavascript("function fun1(){console.log('this is fun1')}", null); 
  }
}
```

I can't call the JavaScript function automatically after page the loaded. I try to use

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    fun1();
  });
</script>
```

But console shows "ReferenceError: fun1 is not defined". I think the 'load' event is fired before the `onPageFinished` method.

I want to know is there an event fired after `onPageFinished`, or I can inject the js function in another method in Android WebViewClient

Comment: It might be JavaScript error so please check js function.

Comment: It's my typo. I fix it in question